# Why does my AJAX data load then disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am loading JSON data from a movie database API. The AJAX loads within a search function, it works fine but then disappears. Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="movie">inserisci film:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie" type="text"></input>
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="search()" class="btn btn-default">cerca</button>
```

Then I call the function

```
function search() {
    var film = document.getElementById('movie').value;
    var key = '?api_key=somekey';
    alert(film + key);
    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie'+key+'&query='+film,
        async: false,
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#titolo').append(data.results[0].original_title);
            $('#immagine').append('<img src=' + url + key +  ata.results[0].poster_path + '></img>');
            console.log(data);
        },              
    });
};
```

there is something wrong? thank you

Comment: You may be being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) as you are making a request to a third party domain. However (and most importantly) **remove `async: false`**. It is *terrible* practice to use it as it blocks the UI thread, making the browser appear to the user as though it has crashed until the request has completed.

Comment: the HTML you provided is not enough, you missed the elements with `titolo` and `immagine` for example

Comment: You do not cancel the submit... The form does what it is supposed to do, send the data to the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You click the submit button
2. The JavaScript runs
3. The ajax request is sent
4. Because `async: false` the entire UI locks up until the JS is done
5. The DOM is updated by the success function
6. The form submits
7. The browser loads a new page

If you are going to use intrinsic event attributes (which you shouldn't), then you need to `return false` from the function to stop the normal behaviour of the event from occurring.

```
onclick="search(); return false;"
```

Comment: yeah he didn't include, it but everything indicates he has. `form-group` which is probably a bootstrap class used under a form and the behaviour of the code.

Comment: you got it, thank you also for suggestion about async

Answer (score 0):

> Its because you submitting form

You Called `search()` function and then after execution form will get submitted as normal flow and redirected to new `url`. You have to return false when submitted.You can do something like this:

```
 complete: function(data){
       return false; 
  }
```